# how do i update text on a page from a database field without refreshing page?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i don't even know where to begin with this one.  probably a combination of php, mysql, jquery, and ajax?

if person 1 has a page open and is viewing values from a database, and person 2 on a different computer edits records that person 1 is currently viewing, is it possible for those values to update on person 1's screen without person 1 having to refresh?

how would i go about doing something like that?  are there any extremely small examples that can be provided with one field, then i can duplicate example to more fields?

not sure this is helpful, but the way i am saving the fields to database is on-the-fly, without refreshing, so i want to somehow add to this below and get the values to auto update on anyone's screen that has the page open when the values are changed in the database by anyone on any computer.

thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('td.edit').click(function(){                  
    $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    $(this).addClass('ajax');
    $(this).html('<input id="editbox" size="'+$(this).text().length+'" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
    $('#editbox').focus();
});

$('td.edit').keydown(function(event){
    arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
    if(event.which == 13) {
        $('table tbody tr').removeClass('footable-detail-show'); //collapse expanded row part1
        $('.footable-row-detail').hide(); //collapse expanded row part2
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"ajax-table-update.php",
            data: "value="+$('.ajax input').val()+"&rownum="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1],
            success: function(data){
                $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                $('#filter').focus();
            }
        });
    }
});

$(document).on('blur','#editbox', function(){
    $('table tbody tr').removeClass('footable-detail-show'); //collapse expanded row part1
    $('.footable-row-detail').hide(); //collapse expanded row part2
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"ajax-table-update.php",
            data: "value="+$('.ajax input').val()+"&rownum="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1],
            success: function(data){
                $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                $('#filter').focus();
            }
        });
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: A Google search for something like "PHP web sockets" should get you going.  For browsers which don't support web sockets, you'd probably also want to support a long polling solution as well.

Comment: you could possibly track if person 1 is active in the page and every once in a while you make the ajax call, somewhat like social networks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it.  Have a file pull from the database like data.php.  Then have an ajax call to that php file from your index.php every 8 seconds.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  refreshdata();
});

function refreshdata(){
    $('#data').load('data.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshdata, 5000);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="data"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

data.php

```
<?php
//Connect to your database here or w/e

//Output here
echo $outputdata;
?>
```

I grabbed this from around and modified it.  It should all work though

Comment: that's to display and update all values in a single div.  what if i wanted to display and update values in different divs?

Comment: i think i understand after testing some more.  thanks for your help.

Comment: however, even though it answers the question and it does work, it doesn't work for the application i'm building.  it's a complicated page, and i guess it needs a complicated solution.  i'll ask this a different way in a different question later on.

Comment: Oh ok,  I am sorry then.  I will see the other question and try to answer it.